# Como convertir un dato de tipo blob a string en java

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, blob

Estoy obteniendo datos desde un procedimiento almacenado y uno de ellos es de tipo blob, pero no logro utilizarlo en java, quiero recibirlo y convertirlo a String para enviarlo en un json

De esta manera lo recibo del SP

```
.logo((String)p.get("LOGITIPO"))
```

en esta parte es donde necesito convertirlo a string por que me manda error desde este punto

Estoy intentando convertirlo con esta forma

```
Blob blob = (Blob) p.get("LOGITIPO");
            byte[] bdata;
            try {
                bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
            
            String s = new String(bdata);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
```

pero no me sale, alguien sabe como hacerlo de la manera correcta?

Comment: `p` qué es, de qué tipo de dato? `p.get("LOGITIPO")` devuelve un `String` o un `Blob`? A parte de lo anterior, si lo que estás almacenando en el `Blob` no es un texto (asumo que es una imagen ya que lo llamas logotipo) cómo esperas obtener un texto a partir de su contenido?

Comment: p.get("LOGITIPO") es donde obtengo los datos de la columna de la tabla de la base de datos, obtiene un tipo blob y quiero convertir ese dato a un string para poder enviarlo en un json

Answer (score 0):

Podes convertirlo a byte[] y de ahi a base64 para mandarlo en un JSON como string:.

```
byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());

String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```